# How can I get my TCP server to constantly receive data?

Tags: java, tcp

It's a stupid novice question, I know. However, on the internet, there are only horrible examples of TCP servers. Like this:

```
try {
    Socket skt = new Socket("localhost", 1332);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
    InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
    System.out.print("Received string: '");

    while (!in.ready()) {}
    System.out.println(in.readLine()); // Read one line and output it
    System.out.print("'\n");
    in.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.print("Whoops! It didn't work!\n");
}
```

How would I make this handle multiple clients, and also be able to constantly receive data instead of just closing the input stream?

There are no easily-found code snippets on the internet for it.

Comment: Your example can't handle multiple clients because it's not a server, it's a client. But the internet is full of Client-Server examples. In fact the Java tutorial most likely contains an example under Networking.

Comment: Yes but they are all dumb tutorials that just take one client and just close the socket after first receiving the data. Do you have any recommendations on a good one?

Comment: You might want to go through the rest of the official tutorial too. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are showing is for a **client**, an application that talks to the server for a specific session.

For a **server** (like [here](https://systembash.com/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/)) one uses a `ServerSocket` where you enter the specific port number. The socket listens to the port and each time someone aims to connect creates a connection. That connection is some kind of session where the server communicates with a client.

A minimal example of a server is thus something like:

```
class TCPServer {

   public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
         int port = 8081;
         ServerSocket waiting = new ServerSocket(port);

         while(true) {
            Socket socket = waiting.accept(); //wait until a client shows up
            new SessionHandler(socket).start();//create new handler with the socket
            //start listening again
         }
      }
}
```

So you run the `.accept` in a `while` loop such that from the moment you received a connection with a client, you wait for another one.

And as `SessionHandler`

```
class SessionHandler extends Thread {

    private Socket socket;

    public SessionHandler (Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run () {
        //handle the session using the socket (example)
        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        //read input from inFromClient, write to outToClient
    }

}
```

Now on an industrial TCP server, the story is of corse a bit more complicated: you will use a *thread pool* to prevent the server from getting too much work, etc.